# Concentrate singular values by diagonal similarity

Tags: linear-algebra

Given non-singular real matrix $A$ of size $n \times n$. I want to find a non-singular diagonal matrix $D$ such that
$$
B = D A D^{-1} 
$$
has singular values $\sigma(B) = [1, \dots, 1, \lvert \det(A) \rvert]$. First, how to determine that such $D$ exists? Second, how to (numerically) compute it?

Comment: This is hopeless. If $A$ is diagonal, then $B=A$. (There are also other problems for more general $A$.)

Comment: @ChristianRemling I agree that there are many cases in which there is no solution, but I’m expecting more a numerical test to determine that a solution exists.